# passing a path in the url as argument code igniter framework

Tags: php

How can I pass a path to a file using the URI assoc

$data = $CI->uri->uri_to_assoc(3, null);

http://localhost/index.php/home/index/fileargument/\shared\path\to\my\file.xml

that does not workout all the backslash get converted to forward slash to then it only captures the first portion “shared” gets saved in my variable.

I checked my config.php file and backlash seems to be allowed ...

Comment: got it working just using get parameters and leaving config.php uri_protocol to AUTO it automatically figures out which one to use, works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you made a route in the routes.php config file like:

```
$route['home/index/fileargument/:any'] = "home/index/fileargument/$1";
```

Comment: Thanks taylor nice idea but that doesn't seem to work, if I use forward slash I again still get the first part of the path and if i use backward slash I get the requested url was not found on server.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to [URL encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) the file path before including it in your URL.  Though to be honest, this sounds like it really should be a case where the query string is going to be superior.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried with this:

```
https://www.programiranje.co.rs/download/%2Fhome%2Fprogram%2Fpy%2Fdownloads%2Fj6lHgeEPuGc.m4a
```

and I did put a route like this:

```
$route["download/(:any)"] = "Main/download/$1";
```

But it kept going to this:

```
https://www.programiranje.co.rs/downloads/j6lHgeEPuGc.m4a
```

Then I realized I just need somehow to encode that path and base64_encode was the best candidate for that job:

```
https://www.programiranje.co.rs/download/L2hvbWUvcHJvZ3JhbS9weS9kb3dubG9hZHMvajZsSGdlRVB1R2MubTRh
```

Nothing can't beat base64_encode!!!